# Different EditForm based on the List View

Tags: sharepoint-designer, list, view, edit-form, newform

We are creating an asset list in Sharepoint 2013 site (on-premise). It will be one big list instead of making separate lists for different item types. There will be different views depending on the item types (furniture, computers, printers etc).

I know there is one out-of-the-box EditForm.aspx and NewForm.aspx. I also know that they can customized and saved with different names in SP designer. One thing I need to know if we be able to pull up the right form depending on from **which view** the Edit link was clicked. Meaning, that I want the EditForm for Furnitures to be displayed instead of the one for printers if the user was in the Furnitures view of the list. If this is possible then I'll appreciate a general guidance on how could it be achieved.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a perfect scenario for utilizing content types. You could create a content type per asset type. It will automatically provide you with menu items in the ***New*** ribbon button for each asset type. For example, new furniture, new computer, etc. Each NewForm and EditForm will contain fields specific to chosen content type. This can all be done with no-code solution, either by SPD or browser.

For more information on content types please refer to the following link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms479905(v=office.14).aspx. It is targeting SP 2010, but it's applicable to SP 2013 as well.

Comment: @Slaven_Semper This sounds great, but can all content types reside in the same list? I think not. For this to work I will have to create separate lists, which I dont want to do. I want the same list for all different asset types because it makes it easier for me to report just by changing the filter or view instead of relying upon some webpart that aggregates different lists into one report for a particular staff or office. I hope I'm making sense? Regardless, thank you for introducing to the Content Type concept. It sounds like a real powerful feature for a newbie like myself.

Comment: You can have multiple content types per list. I myself have worked on projects with 20+ content types per list.

Comment: Gotcha. I didn't know that. Thank you. Will give it a try.

Comment: the content type solution is working beautifully. There are only two road blocks so far. I was hoping to add separate buttons in the List ribbon for each asset/content type. I tried various solutions in SP designer but nothing is working. I can live without it, but the other one is very  important and I have posted it as a separate question as follows: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/q/126411/33301