# Different sets of options in a lookup or choice column depending on the content type

Tags: 2013, content-type, lookup-column, choice-field

I have a list content type and other content types that derive from it. I need to add a lookup or choice column to the content type (or the list itself) just so that each child content type or list has separate set of options.

For example the parent content type is Assets. The content types deriving from it are Computers and Furniture. I need to add a column named "Asset_Type" that will list "Desktop, Laptop, Tablet" if the content type is Computer and it will list "Table, Chair, Desk" if the content type is Furniture.

I tried various scenarios with site columns but everytime ended up overwriting the parent column options and vice-versa. What should I be doing to make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add two separate site columns, one for each derived content type.

You could name first site column "computer asset type" for use in "computer" content type with lookup or choice values "desktop,lptop,tablet". Similarly, you could name second site column "furniture asset type" for use in "furniture" content type with lookup or choice values "table,chair,desk"

**EDIT:**

If you choose to use solution with one generic column then you should inject the following JavaScript code to forms used for entering and editing list data:

```
var dropdown = $("select[title='Asset type']");

// If content type equals "Computer" then remove first 3 options
if (document.URL.indexOf("Computer") != -1 && document.URL.indexOf("Upload.aspx") != -1) {
    dropdown.find("option[value='1']").remove();
    dropdown.find("option[value='2']").remove();
    dropdown.find("option[value='3']").remove();
}

// If content type equals "Furniture" then remove last 3 options
if (document.URL.indexOf("Furniture") != -1 && document.URL.indexOf("Upload.aspx") != -1) {
    dropdown.find("option[value='4']").remove();
    dropdown.find("option[value='5']").remove();
    dropdown.find("option[value='6']").remove();
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Slaven. Yeah I could have done that, but I was hoping to create a generic column "Sub_Type" in the parent content type when showing in the AllItems View in which all the assets (computers, furnitures etc) are listed. I would prefer not to show two separate columns for the generic view.

Comment: You could have 2 views, one for each content type. In each of the views you can then hide column which is not used. Solution with one generic column is also an option but it requires injecting a piece of javascript code which would hide certain values from dropdown list based on selected content type.

Comment: Yes I got that. I guess then there is no OOTB solution to have a single view that lists all the assets with their sub types shown in a single generic subtype column. Fair enough. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Another thing. When I added the [Content Type] column in the view by marking the checkbox, I was expecting to see the actual child content type (Computer, Furniture etc). Instead I only see "item" listed under the [Content Type] column. How can I get the actual child content type name?

Comment: This leads to another question. How do I filter on Computers only content type when I am creating a view for computers only. As I mentioned earlier, the [Content Type] column returns only the generic "item" string and not the immediate "Computer" or "Furniture".

Comment: I have edited my answer to include JavaScript needed for a solution with one generic column. If you create new list item via menu `New` then Content type column should contain that information. Can you make sure you created new item with form which showed fields specific to chosen content type?

Comment: Thanks for the javascript code!  I have created custom NEW pages (like NewComputer.aspx, NewFurniture.aspx) in SP Designer which are attached to the respective content types. I have created links to get to those pages through side nav bar. However, I am still not able to get to the custom new pages using the choices under the top ribbon's NEW menu item. They just take me to the default NewItem.aspx page. I am not worried about it as long as it is taking me to the right content page, but could this affect the Content Type column value which is not setting to the right content type and ...

Comment: instead shows the default content type "item".

Comment: Why are you creating custom forms? Built-in forms allow you to choose content type when creating new list item.

Comment: Yes I have created built-in forms through SP designer UI. I called them custom form because they are not OOTB NewItem.aspx or EditItem.aspx.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19928/discussion-between-slaven-semper-and-aamir).