# Filter Checkbox Options on Content Type

Tags: javascript, content-type

I have a field with multiple checkbox options that is shared across multiple different content types. I need to keep the column as-is but also filter so that only certain checkboxes show based upon the content type.

As an example.

- Site column choice with checkboxes, title='Fruits'
- 'Fruits' values='Apples, Oranges, Pears, Peaches, Pineapple'
- Content types = North, South, West

New form is OOTB to select content type

- If Content type='North' then column 'Fruits' should only show 'Oranges,
  Pineapple' checkboxes
- If Content type='South' then column 'Fruits' should only show 'Pears,
  Peaches' etc.

I found another thread but it addressed drop-downs. It also didn't work for me to target my content types, otherwise this is what I want to do: [Different sets of options in a lookup or choice column depending on the content type](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/126411/different-sets-of-options-in-a-lookup-or-choice-column-depending-on-the-content)

Changing this column into multiple columns is not an option unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you create your own URL to NewForm.aspx without parameters,
the ContentTypeId is by default present as a QueryString parameter.

So you can add some JavaScript to that single NewForm.aspx that matches by ContentTypeId and hide values

```
   JSRequest.EnsureSetup();
    var ctID=JSRequest.QueryString['ContentTypeId'];
    var titles={
        '0x0100.. ContentTypeID' : 'North',
        '0x0100.. ContentTypeID' : 'South',
    '0x0100.. ContentTypeID' : 'West'
    };
    var title = titles[ctID] || ctID;
   if(title=='North')
    {
        if($('#ControlID').closest('tr').find('table tr input[type="checkbox"]').closest(".ms-RadioText[title='Apples']").hide()
    }
```